# htaccess subdomain redirct with last url parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to write a .htaccess file for redirecting my subdomains and URL's last variable to a new location. Here is what I want to do:

> http(s)://abc.example.com/books

I want my internal URL to be like:

> http://example.com/?name=abc&type=books

I have already gotten the subdomain redirect to work but I am not able to do subdomain with variable in last part of URL.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's customary, if your problem has been solved by one of the answers below, to check the mark next to that answer. This helps others know that your problem has been fixed and you're saying thanks to the person answering.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)% http://example.com/?name=%1&type=$1 [R,L]
```

The "%1" means use the first capture group from the RewriteCond above.

Comment: Thank you Greg
 for your comment but can you please make further and and rule for url like,
http://abc.example.com/books
and I want both variables "abc" and "books" also. and I want to redirect it to a profile.php

Comment: That will do "abc" and "books"

Comment: Hey Greg yo are great man. I was stumbling upon this problem from so much time. so solved.

Thank you verymuch

Comment: There's a typo .. "%" instead of "$" in the regex :)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://example.com/?name=%1&type=$1 [R,L]
```

The `"%1"` means use the first capture group from the RewriteCond, while `$1` is the first capturing group in the rule itself.

In your example `%1` will be "abc" and `$1` will be "book"

`[^/]*` means "match every character **not being** a slash, 0 or more times"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation my problem get solved and I'm getting both variables

Thank you very much.