# htaccess redirect for subdomains -> similarly-named subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I'm restructuring a web site with a great deal of content currently parked at URLs that look like this.

http://string.domain.com/year/month/dd/string-pulled-from-title

For various reasons, I'd like to park all new content at URLs that looks like this

http://www.domain.com/blogs/string/year/month/dd/string-pulled-from-title

I'd like to make the change for future content, but don't want all the old stuff to go 404.

I believe a 301 redirect rule in my htaccess will do the trick, sending all referred traffic coming in through old links to the new formats.

But what should this rule look like?  I've read a few tutorials but haven't found this exact case in any examples.

Note, I don't want to do this for all subdomains, only for about 10 specific ones.  So if someone could help me figure out one of these, then I can copy paste it 10 times in  my htaccess for each subdomain and be set.

Answer (score 4):

Drop this into the `.htaccess` file of the old site (adjusting the domain to your actual one):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/string/$1 [R=301]
```

This will grab this part of the URL at the old site:

```
year/month/dd/string-pulled-from-title
```

and redirect it to the new site under the new location:

```
blogs/string/year/month/dd/string-pulled-from-title
```

Alternatively, if you want something a little more variable like, without having to custom fix each `.htaccess`, drop this in the file for each subdomain instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're redirecting to the same domain, and it includes the [www](http://no-www.org/), adjust the rewrite rules to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the second `RewriteCond` which checks to make sure that the URL requested **does not** include the leading `www`, which may lead to an endless redirect if the destination URL itself includes `www` and would try and redirect that subdomain as well.

- **`%1`** [grabs the first capture group from the line above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133106/htaccess-subdomain-redirct-with-last-url-parameter/1133165#1133165).
- **`$1`**  references the first capture group on the same line.

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what I was getting at, I need to do something a little more complex.  Would this work?

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 http://www.example.com/blogs/$1/$2 [R=301]

That's the structure of what I need to do.  But would that syndtax work?

Comment: Not really, but have taken that and applied up the edit to allow for a more flexible solution.

Comment: That created a redirect loop.  Here's what appears in the address bar when I paste those two lines in your example into my htaccess file.

http://www.example.com/blogs/www?q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/www&q=blogs/string

I'd like it say http://www.example.com/blogs/string

Comment: Ah, didn't account for the leading www, so have adjusted the answer in that case.

Comment: Awesome.  That worked like a charm for fixing broken links to my old blog posts.  Is there a way I can edit it so it only triggers for URLs that have stuff after the example.com?  I'd like to redirect "subdomain.example.com" according to a different set of rules than "subdomain.example.com/something".  

This is the last missing piece.  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you put `$` at the end of the domain in the `RewriteCond` that will stop it at that point in matching. Otherwise it will match to all that start the same, but may end differently.