# htaccess, redirect virtual subdomain to URL parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, url-parameters

I have a .ne.ro domain (registered in Romania) where visitors can enter with or without 'www':

`http://mydomain.ne.ro`
`http://www.mydomain.ne.ro`

I want to redirect `http://123.mydomain.ne.ro` to `http://mydomain.ne.ro?id=123`. If visitor enter with 'www|mail|ftp' must be treated as non parameter (obviously).

I tried [htaccess subdomain redirct with last url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133106/htaccess-subdomain-redirct-with-last-url-parameter) but didn't work.

Current code:

```
# edited on 05/April/2011 as suggested:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?id=%1 [R,L]
```

---

*Hosted on a [hostgator's business plan](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) (linux) and registered at [nic.ro](http://nic.ro), just if asking.*

Comment: What is the current redirect rule?

Comment: Anybody? I'm newbie and stuck in this issue.

Comment: You don't need no redirects. All requests **already** land to your index.

Comment: I stopped following up on this question for 3 months (busy with other site). Well, mydomain.ne.ro still has this issue, the code was edited and doesn't work yet; any idea about how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many suggested code (thanks [supersuphot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519160/supersuphot)) and a lot of research finally I found an answer.

First I added the subdomain ***** under **mydomain.ne.ro**, pointed to domain folder/path:

[image: Create subdomain *, hostgator shared account]

Then I uploaded .htaccess file with the next code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain.ne.ro
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.ne.ro
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://mydomain.ne.ro/?id=%1 [P,L]
```

this works too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?id=%1 [P,L]
```

The most important thing is the ***P*** instead ***R*** at last line, to keep original subdomain. Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/235879/keeping-the-original-subdomain-url-in-the-address-bar-with-wildcard-subdomains/235893#235893) to a [related question](https://serverfault.com/q/235879/74687).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.ne\.ro$
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.ne.ro?id=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried it without positive results. Your rules made me research and finally I got it.

Comment: I didn't know that it was necessary, it was a headache discover why (:

Answer (score 1):

Wow quantme !

I'm searching that code since two days , eh finally ...

Your first code is perfect for me

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://mydomain.ne.ro/?id=%1 [P,L]
```

Also You can change with this(for Uppercase or Lowercase letters )

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.ne.ro/?id=%1 [P,L]
```

Many Thanks quantme