# Mod-rewrite for domain except one directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a novice at htaccess and can't figure out what's going on here.  I am trying to get all redirects to point index.php with the PAGEID=pageName.

So, domain.com/manager would get pushed to index.php?PAGEID=manager.

Now, I have this working but I need it to just act normally when it hits the directory 'test', but whenever I goto domain.com/test I get pushed to index.php?PAGEID=test

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule ^([\w/]*)$ index.php?PAGEID=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic is having some problems. Because in this example 'domain.com/test', we have write a condition as replace all strings(test) after domain.com to 'index.php?pageid=test'.

The problem is 'index.php' is also coming as a string after domain 'domain.com/index.php?pageid..' . Here also the rewrite condition will be applicable and it will rewrite it.

I think you should try something like this.
[htaccess, redirect virtual subdomain to URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089750/htaccess-redirect-virtual-subdomain-to-url-parameter)

Or if 'test' is a static string, then in the rewrite condition we can specify as replace only string 'test' to 'index.php/pageid=test'