# htaccess multiple subdomain to multiple url's

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm not sure how to best approach this.

We have several salespeople here and each want a subdomain ie:

```
http://johndoe.mydomain.com
```

However, we have all of their profiles on the site displayed dynamically, IE:

```
http://mydomain.com/sales/index.php?person=jdoe
```

We have about 15 salespeople, and eventually I will have time to script this out as new profiles are entered.  For now, I can hand edit a .htaccess file if need be.  All of the examples I have seen seem to redirect to a specific domain or subfolder.  How should I approach this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: After more searching, I ended up finding the answer at[htaccess-redirect-virtual-subdomain-to-url][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089750/htaccess-redirect-virtual-subdomain-to-url-parameter?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You place this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}         ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule  ^/?$                 /index.php?person=%1          [P,L,QSA]
```

This would be more generic:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}         ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule  ^.*$                 /index.php?person=%1&page=$0  [P,L,QSA]
```

The problem could also be solved at the PHP level:

```
$domain_array = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$person = $domain_array[0];
```

Or:

```
if (preg_match("@^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$@", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], $match)){
    $person = $match[1];
} else{
    $person = "";
}
```