# Subdomain redirect to URL Parameter while keeping other url params intact

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I've looked like crazy for an answer to this - and I haven't been able to find one as of yet. My apologies in advance if I've missed something.

I'm looking to convert a subdomain to a url parameter while maintaining the other url pieces.

Such as:

http://sub.domain.tv/value redirects to http://domain.tv/value?campus=sub

This is what I've tried after looking through numerous posts on here:

```
# campus
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.tv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tv/$1/?campus=sub [R=301,L]
```

which worked fine for redirecting sub.domain.tv to domain.tv?campus=sub, but does not work with the rest of the URL parameters (so heading to sub.domain.tv/value does nothing).

I've tried other examples with the %1 and $1 being used as variables, such as with this post:
[htaccess subdomain redirct with last url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133106/htaccess-subdomain-redirct-with-last-url-parameter) but I don't understand the difference (and the examples I've tried did not work).

Thanks for taking a look! :) I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [QSA] parameter.  This will add any remaining Query parameters to `campus=sub`

Comment: Terry, thanks so much for the response! I haven't, I'll look into it and let you know!

Comment: Looks like [QSA] moves the value to being *behind* the parameters - so .tv/value would rewrite to .tv/?campus=subvalue, whereas I need them to remain before them. so that .tv/value translates to .tv/value?campus=sub -- at least, that is what this site says: 

"When capturing variables, the first thing you need to know about, is the [QSA] flag, which simply tags all the original variables back onto the end of the target url." [via : http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php ]

I appreciate the suggestion tho!

Comment: `/value` is _not_ a parameter in URI terms; its part of the resource path. (A parameter is ?print=1.)  So QSA does apply here.  This rule would redirect `http://sub.domain.tv/value` to `http://domain.tv/value/?campus=sub`  If you don't want the last "/" then drop it after the `$1`.