# redirect page to variable url in php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, header

Two Questions

**1. i want to redirect "www.example.com/`variable`" -> "www.example.com/member/signup?upline=`variable`"**

Note: i have wordpress installed at example.com/wp-admin

and here's what .htaccess looks like :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**2. how to redirect "`variable`.example.com" -> "www.example.com/member/signup?upline=`variable`"**

without making seperate subdomains for each variable.

Note: wordpress is still installed at the same location, htaccess looks same too.

Comment: Do you want an internal redirect, so the URL stays the same? Or do you want the URL to change?

Comment: @showdev same url

Comment: Does this answer your questions? [htaccess subdomain redirct with last url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133106/htaccess-subdomain-redirct-with-last-url-parameter)

Comment: _“i have wordpress installed at example.com/wp-admin”_ - that would be the admin backend - which likely means, you actually have WordPress installed just directly in the domain root? Which means, WP itself will rewrite everything of the form `www.example.com/variable` to its own index.php already. Which means, your requirement here is kinda incompatible with reality to begin with. You have no real means to decide on .htaccess level, whether WP itself has content to serve for `/variable`. If anything, you would probably have to handle this from within WordPress.